# String Slicing with If?

Tags: python, string, if-statement

started a class on Python this semester and I'm having troubles with a current assignment. Went through the examples and exercises done in class uptil now and couldn't find anything.

Q1) Fixed

```
aN = raw_input("Enter a number with decimals")
bN = raw_input("Enter a binary number, 2 to 4 digits in length")

if (bN[-1] == 1):
    print "The binary number was odd so your number will contain 2 decimals"
    print "The number is now",aN[0:4],

elif (bN[-1] == 0):
    print "The binary number was even so your number will contain 1 decimal"
    print "The number is now",bN[0:3]
```

I want it to be able to print out two statements, one for each outcome. If the binary number entered ends with a "1" it would spit out aN with 2 decimals and if the binary number entered ends with a "0" it would spit out aN with 1 decimal.

When it runs, it doesn't do anything after showing the value the user inputs for bN

Q2) Is there a better way to find digits after the decimal? The slicing only works when it's numbers < 10.

edit) Ty to the guy that pointed out the string, I totally forgot that :(

```
aN = raw_input("Enter a number with decimals")
bN = raw_input("Enter a binary number, 2 to 4 digits in length")

if (float(bN[-1]) == 1):
    print "The binary number was odd so your number will contain 2 decimals"
    print "The number is now",aN[0:4],

elif (float(bN[-1]) == 0):
    print "The binary number was even so your number will contain 1 decimal"
    print "The number is now",aN[0:3]
```

If anyone could answer the second question though, that would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by "spit out aN with 2 decimals"? can you give an example input of aN and bN, and the expected output? Also the output from your codes.

Comment: Suppose User enters 1.23456 when asked to enter a number with decimals (aN) and 11 when asked to enter a binary number (bN). The last digit of the binary number was 1 so aN will now be given back to the user as 1.23. If the binary number was 0 instead of 1, the number given back to the user would be 1.2

Comment: `1 == '1'` <-- this statement is False - you are comparing strings to integers to I doubt anything is working as expected. Try `if bn[-1] == '1':` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming aN always have at least 1 decimals, this should be working. You can use `find()` to locate the "." for decimals.

```
aN = raw_input("Enter a number with decimals")
bN = raw_input("Enter a binary number, 2 to 4 digits in length")

if (bN[-1] == "1"):
    print "The binary number was odd so your number will contain 2 decimals"
    print "The number is now", aN[:aN.find(".")+3]

elif (bN[-1] == "0"):
    print "The binary number was even so your number will contain 1 decimal"
    print "The number is now", aN[:aN.find(".")+2]
```

Example:

```
>>> aN
'1.12345'
>>> bN
'11'
>>> if (bN[-1] == "1"):
...     print "The binary number was odd so your number will contain 2 decimals"
...     print "The number is now", aN[:aN.find(".")+3]
... elif (bN[-1] == "0"):
...     print "The binary number was even so your number will contain 1 decimal"
...     print "The number is now", aN[:aN.find(".")+2]
...
The binary number was odd so your number will contain 2 decimals
The number is now 1.12
```

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input()` takes the input as string. In your `if` condition you are compering a string with a integer. make your `if` like this,

```
if float(bN[-1]) == 1:
    print "The binary number was odd so your number will contain 2 decimals"
    print "The number is now %.2f" % float(aN)

elif float(bN[-1]) == 0:
    print "The binary number was even so your number will contain 1 decimal"
    print "The number is now", bN[0:3]
```

If you want to print 2 digits after the decimal point, you can follow this approach.